# Why send a notice to evict if the tenant has already left?

Tags: tenant, michigan, eviction

My wife and I were living at an apartment complex in Michigan with property managers from hell. Long story short, we decided it was worth leaving the lease early. There was a lease contract buy-out agreement wherein we could buy-out early given a 60 day notice and a fee equal to two months rent. So we gave them 60 days written notice that we were moving out at the end of August, paid the fee, etc.

On Aug. 25, I got into an argument with the property manager (about their maintenance people being in our way while we're trying to move out). She was belligerent and rude, and told me that I was not on the lease, and so we could be evicted. This was true. My wife was the only one on the lease, because she was the only one of us living there at first. We hadn't thought it a big deal for me to move in with her and had not obtained permission from the landlord. I was upset enough with the interaction that I spent the next two hours writing a very detailed Google review about the apartment complex and everything we'd gone through there.

We permanently moved out on Aug. 29 (and to another state), gave them their keys back, left a forwarding address, etc. The landlord accepted our early termination payment. They even sent us a check to reimburse us for the security deposit. Today (Sept. 19), we received a "Notice to Quit" letter from a Michigan law office representing the landlord, stating that we must move out by Sept. 30 or face the possibility of eviction. The primary reason given was breach of lease terms due to an authorized occupant (me). The letter was dated Aug. 28 (three days after I posted the Google review), but wasn't mailed until Aug. 30 (the day after we left). We didn't receive it until today due to the letter having gone through the USPS forwarding process.

My question is, why? Why write a Notice to Quit if you've had 60 days notice that the tenant will leave in several days? Why mail a Notice to Quit after the tenant has already dropped off the keys and left the premises? It seems so bizarre to me that I'm wondering if there is something that I'm missing. Are we exposed somehow, and this Notice to Quit is simply a first step? Is it possible for them to start an eviction case against us after we've left and seek a judgment against us simply, for example to get us into the eviction records system as revenge for the Google review? Do I respond to the letter or just ignore it?

Comment: As written, I think you can rewrite this to be more general, but the question is answerable in regards to the exposure you might have. I'm going to vote to close, but if you rewrite it in more general terms, I think it's easy to reopen.